# Problem to create room database's "Entity" class from JsonArray/DataModel class in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, entity, android-room, jsonresponse

I am new for the room database. I have facing a problem to create Entity class from below JsonArray.

Can you help to create Entity class from the below file:

```
[
{
"id":1,
"name":"Leanne Graham",
"username":"Bret",
"email":"Sincere@april.biz",
"address":{
"street":"Kulas Light",
"suite":"Apt. 556",
"city":"Gwenborough",
"zipcode":"92998-3874",
"geo":{
"lat":"-37.3159",
"lng":"81.1496"
}
},
"phone":"1-770-736-8031 x56442",
"website":"hildegard.org",
"company":{
"name":"Romaguera-Crona",
"catchPhrase":"Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
"bs":"harness real-time e-markets"
}
},
{
"id":2,
"name":"Ervin Howell",
"username":"Antonette",
"email":"Shanna@melissa.tv",
"address":{
"street":"Victor Plains",
"suite":"Suite 879",
"city":"Wisokyburgh",
"zipcode":"90566-7771",
"geo":{
"lat":"-43.9509",
"lng":"-34.4618"
}
},
"phone":"010-692-6593 x09125",
"website":"anastasia.net",
"company":{}
}
]
```

and **My data model class** as below

```
    data class MyModel (
    val id: Long,
    val name: String,
    val username: String,
    val email: String,
    val address: Address,
    val phone: String,
    val website: String,
    val company: Company
){

}
data class Address (
    val street: String,
    val suite: String,
    val city: String,
    val zipcode: String,
    val geo: Geo
)
data class Geo (
    val lat: String,
    val lng: String
)

data class Company (
    val name: String,
    val catchPhrase: String,
    val bs: String
)
```

I have no idea that my data model class is correct or not and how to generate **Entity class from my data model or Json** response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can probably have only one `@Entity` -> `User` and others you can use as `@Embeded` objects.

```
@Entity
data class User (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0,

    val name: String,
    val username: String,
    val email: String,
    @Embedded val address: Address,
    val phone: String,
    val website: String,
    @Embedded val company: Company
)
```

[image]

**The full source code is here**: https://github.com/dautovicharis/sos_android/tree/q_68390737

**Read more about Room DB here**: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: Cay you provide a json/entity sample of foreign key used and type converter used.

Comment: @KetanPatel Sure, I'll push new changes with this case -> I'll let you know.

Comment: @KetanPatel I have pushed new changes with a custom converter for the Address model class. If you don't have any specific reason it's better to stay with Embeded. For more complex cases please check the official Google example -> https://github.com/android/sunflower

Answer (score 1):

You can install JSON TO Kotlin class plugin and use it. for doing this:

1. In Android Studio choose File -> Settings
2. Search for Plugins
3. Select Marketplace and search "JSON TO Kotlin class".

[image]

After installing the plugin restart Android studio. Now you can use this plugin for converting JSON to Kotlin class. for doing this press Alt + k or follow bellow steps:

1- go to code

2- select generate

3- select Kotlin data classes from json

now paste the JSON and after providing a class name click generate button. for your JSON the result is:

```
data class MyModelItem(
    val address: Address,
    val company: Company,
    val email: String,
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val phone: String,
    val username: String,
    val website: String
)

data class Address(
    val city: String,
    val geo: Geo,
    val street: String,
    val suite: String,
    val zipcode: String
)

class Company(
)

data class Geo(
    val lat: String,
    val lng: String
)
```

Now you can create an entity like bellow:

```
@Entity
data class MyModelEntity(
 @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
 val id: Int,
 val city: String,
 val lat: String,
 val lng: String,
 val street: String,
 val suite: String,
 val zipcode: String,
 val company: Company,
 val email: String,
 val name: String,
 val phone: String,
 val username: String,
 val website: String
)
```

In your dao you can insert data as bellow:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun addToDatabase(model: MyModelEntity?): Long
```

Finally in your repositoy you can use bellow codes:

```
 fun insertToDatabase(myModelItem: MyModelItem) {
    val myModelEntity = MyModelEntity(
        city = myModelItem.address.city,
        lat = myModelItem.address.lat,
        lng = myModelItem.address.lng,
        street = myModelItem.address.street,
        suite = myModelItem.address.suite,
        zipcode = myModelItem.address.zipcode,
        company = myModelItem.company,
        email = myModelItem.email,
        name = myModelItem.name,
        phone = myModelItem.phone,
        username = myModelItem.username,
        website = myModelItem.website
    )
    dao.addToDatabase(myModelEntity)
}
```

Comment: ok, Now how to generate entity class from them? Can you please provide entity class

Comment: what to do if have array of phone? TypeConverter is used but how to use it?